# Unable to load DLL 'opencv_highgui248': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, opencv

I have a simple OpenCvSharp Project. I added the compatible references and imported opencv dll to the project. the system is set to x86 and almost everything is double checked but I still get this error. I searched for 2 hours and performed al the suggestions for the similar problems but still unsolved. Please someone advice me for solving my problem.

```
 class FastFeatureDector : FeatureDetector
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IplImage img = new IplImage(@"....\tree.gif");
            CvWindow w = new CvWindow("test");

            while (CvWindow.WaitKey(10)< 0)
            {
                using (IplImage gray = new IplImage(img.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1))
                using (IplImage dstCanny = new IplImage(img.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1))
                {
                    img.CvtColor(gray, ColorConversion.BgrToGray);
                    Cv.Canny(gray, dstCanny, 50, 50, ApertureSize.Size3);
                    w.Image = dstCanny;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Unable to load DLL 'opencv_highgui248': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: I just figured out that I have not copied the opencv_highgui248.dll in to the debug folder. now the previous error is gone.                    I also realized that openCVSharp is not capable of opening other formats than jpg and Avi (for me mp4, and gif is not working!)

Comment: Heh, if you're using Microsoft Visual Studio you can configure your include, library etc. direcotries in project properties - makes it all a lot cleaner ;) As for OpenCV well, there you have it. But hey, it's free :P Use Python ;)